# Counterexample to triangle inequality?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z_1=2-i$ and $z_2=3-2i$. Now, we have$|z_1|=5\ \ |z_2|=13$. But, $|z_1+z_2|=|5-3i|=34>|z_1|+|z_2|$! What am I missing here? As another part of the question, let $z_1=a+ib,z_2=c+id$. Then, $|z_1|=a^2+b^2,|z_2|=c^2+d^2$ and $|z_1+z_2|=|(a+c)+i(b+d)|=(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2$. From this, if triangle inequality be true, we get, after canceling equal terms, $2(ac+bd)\le0$, which is not always true! Where is the mistake? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you forgot to take the square root: For example:

$$|z_1|= \sqrt{5}$$

$$|z_2|= \sqrt{13}$$

Comment: oh, just a square root cost me to think about this for hours on end! Shall I delete the question?